# iOS Safari loads a wrong page

Tags: ios, safari, phalcon

I've met a very strange bug when tried to open my web site http://akr-congress2016.ru/ in iOS Safari. Please see the screenshot below.

It seems like some elements are loaded from a completely other web site. The new site is a copy of the old one, but layout files (I'm using Phalcon) are changed. There is no link to the old web site at the page.

Also I've noticed doubled logo, it seems like a rendering bug.

When I refresh the page it is loaded normally.

I'm weird what might make Safari to load some fragments of the page from completely another domain.

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXL9m.png)

Comment: Looks just fine for me on iPhone 6 and Simulator (both latests iOS) http://puu.sh/oo57c/486792872c.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove cache from browser. Or maybe it's just an issue of DNS. In that case you just need to wait untill DNS will get updated.